# Animate container with color after process is completed create password flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPnTN.png)
I am trying to implement multi step password creation similar to multi step checkout in flutter. How to fill them with color after validation success?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Animated Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html) widget. It can animate Container properties as they change

You can use it in the following way

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _color = Colors.blueGrey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _color =
                    _color == Colors.blueGrey ? Colors.indigo : Colors.blueGrey;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 240),
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            color: _color,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```